# CMV How to use growler

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I am trying to use growler into a plugin, does anybody know how to set up a working growler or can point to some documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use it out-of-the-box. Here's an example usage (From the Directions widget):

```
            topic.publish('growler/growl', {
                title: 'Title',
                message: 'message',
                level: 'default',
                timeout: 10000,
                opacity: 1.0
            });
```

https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/bf497c6e6671c184bf12a76979a9a02425e897e5/viewer/js/gis/dijit/Directions.js#L108-L113

Don't forget to include "dojo/topic" in your AMD includes of the widget in which you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have growler free standing here:
https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/growler-widget-js